# Find and replace with {Tab} key

Tags: windows-7

I have this in a txt-file

```
task a
task b
Lindberg's note: blah
    task b.1
    task b.2
task c
task d
```

I want this

```
task a
task b
    Lindberg's note: blah
    task b.1
    task b.2
task c
task d
```

So, how do I create a find & replace, but instead of "find x, replace with y" I want "find Lindberg's note, replace with {Tab key}Lindberg's note".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy some text, containing {Tab} character, e.g. "    task b.1"

Bring "Find and replace dialog"

Insert copied string to "Replace" box and edit the text, not deleting the {Tab} representative (in my notepad.exe it's shown as a box character)

Comment: In my notepad.exe it can only paste the first line.

Comment: can you select just a {Tab} whitespace and copy it to buffer? Can it be inserted in the dialog after that?

Comment: Yes. And I feel very stupid now.